# loading an iframe dynamically.

Tags: iframe, extjs5

Im trying to load an iframe onto a container dynamically.
there are two buttons a and b, on clicking each of them a different url should load onto the iframe.

I have tried-
1.using two different containers instead of one as shown below..during
   which browser crashes.
2. i was not able to switch the content inside the container by using dom.clear.
3. should i consider using a different xtype?. since container positions the iframe right on the spot where i wanted it to.

Ext.define('xxxxxx', {
    extend: 'yyyyy',
    width: '100%',
    height: 125,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'radiogroup',
        columns: 2,
        width: 400,
        horizontal: true,
        name:'canvas',
        items: [
                        {
                            boxLabel: 'a',
                            id: 'i1',
                            inputValue: 'i1',
                            handler: function () {

```
                            var iframe = new Ext.ux.IFrame({
                                src: 'https://www.sencha.com',
                                title: 'Hello',
                                width: "100%",
                                height: 1400,
                                renderTo: 'canvas'
                            });

                        }
                    },
                    {
                        boxLabel: 'b',
                        id: 'i2',
                        inputValue: 'i2',
                        handler: function () {
                        var iframe = new Ext.ux.IFrame({
    src: 'https://www.sencha.com/web-application-lifecycle-management-sencha-platform/',
                                width: "100%",
                                height: 1400,
                                renderTo: 'canvas'
                            });                                
                        }
                    }
            ]
},
{
    xtype: 'container',
    name: 'somename',
    id: 'canvas',       
}]
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I had to destroy each of the iframe objects that were created. 
This could dynamically load iframe source as long as it wanted.

```
handler: function () {

 if (iframe != undefined) 
   {
       iframe.destroy();
    }
var iframe = new Ext.ux.IFrame({                   

         src: 'https://www.sencha.com/web-application-lifecycle-management-sencha-platform/',
         width: "100%",
         height: 1400,
         renderTo: 'canvas'

    });                                
}
```